# Resolving merge conflict with several commits on a branch

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a master branch, branch_a, branch_b
branch_a I cut from master where I have local & origin commits as a1, a2, a3, a4
Now I cut branch_b where I have local & origin commits as b1, b2, b3, b4

now I merged branch_b with the master [squashed the commits from branch_b] hence my branch_a is conflicted (I am editing same files in both)
when I try to resolve these conflict it start resolving them from the commit a1 while I want to resolve from a4 as the changes b/w a1,2,3,4 doesn't matter for me

Is squashing going to help?

I am thinking about squashing. But want to know official/better process?

edit: this doesn't intend to prevent conflicts it just means to reduce it.

Comment: What do you mean by "official"? What would you consider to be a better process?

Comment: For me squashing helped, however it would be good to know if any other method is available.

Comment: I don't think squashing has any effect on whether a merge will conflict or not.

Comment: well the squashing saved me from multiple conflicts I had to resolve with each commit, when squashed there is just one time I have to resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try not to work by yourself on two branches and especially on the same lines. (Why would you want to do this to yourself?)

Merge conflicts arise when you have conflicting changes which were made on both branches participating in the merge. I reckon you are on par with that.

By merging a branch with multiple new commits you can have merge conflicts with every commit and you have to resolve them for every commit one at a time.

This is not necessarily a problem which just disappears if you squash the commits, but the merge conflicts get combined or might cancel out.

When you get to the point that you resolve a merge conflict, you are deciding on which piece of code should live on, on the branch on which you are merging your changes for every conflict. This is very dependent on the situation and that is why this can't be answered in general. Aren't there more senior peers whom you can consult?

Comment: (Why would you want to do this to yourself?) our project requires me to push PRs and wait till those are approved hence I have to work on same files and cannot wait till those are approved.
(You can say why not make all changes and then push PR ) I also want to make my PRs granular so that they can be tracked with the Jira ID they belong to. Hence it is a conundrum.

Comment: If company-/project policy mandates it, one should seek a better story writeup, such that the changes between two stories do not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to master.

```
git cherry-pick <id-of-commit-a4>
```

As a result, the changes from the commit are brought to the Staging Area. You need to resolve any conflicts and then commit them. Keep in mind cherry-picking isn't merging. You need the pick other commits that you want to apply to master, too.